# class property displayed name in propertygrid

Tags: .net, vb.net, properties, propertygrid

How do I set the displayed name of property in the property grid?

```
Public Property WeldOrientation As Double
```

WeldOrientation is not proper formatted, a space between the two words is required. How do you set the displayed name for a property?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DisplayName` attribute:

```
<DisplayName("Weld Orientation")>
Public Property WeldOrientation As Double
```

You may have to add a reference to `System.ComponentModel` to use it.